# pdfMake callback when export is finished

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

Is there a way to specify a callback function for the pdfMake's `createPdf` function? I have a large `vfs_fonts.js` file and that's why my export is slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a callback function getDataUrl:

```
this.getDataUrl(function(result) {
    win.location.href = result;
});
```

This function is used by the open, save, and print functions that come built in.  You can see their source here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/81de2c6a97ffb102f8c8c86ea9d7adf97e65976e/src/browser-extensions/pdfMake.js#L50

Using those functions, you should be able to build your own callback that does what you need.

You can use getDataUrl with something like

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getDataUrl(function(url) { alert('your pdf is done'); });
```

You would of course want more than that since you want to give them a way to do something with the completed PDF.

To add a callback after the download is done:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('file.pdf', function() { alert('your pdf is done'); });
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataUrl' of undefined

Comment: Hm, I'm doing all this by reading source code since I don't use pdfMake.  Can you post your code for generating the pdf?  Does normal usage like `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefination).open()` work?  Also, what version of pdfMake are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, you were right. I wanted to call the `getDataUrl` after the `download` function. Also the `download` has callback parameter.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's the problem is adding it after download.  You're actually in luck, the download function has a callback parameter.  I'll add that in my answer.  (Only download has a callback parameter so you won't be able to use this with open or print.)

Comment: what if pdf download fails? where the failure message should go? or this callback is for both ?

Comment: Looking at the source (https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/81de2c6a97ffb102f8c8c86ea9d7adf97e65976e/src/browser-extensions/pdfMake.js#L84) I believe the callback is right after the user is prompted for the downloaded rather than when it is actually fully downloaded to their computer so their is no message for success vs failure of the download.

Comment: The download() function does not even accept a callback option.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/master/build/pdfmake.js

Comment: The 0.1.x branch still has a callback: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/0.1/src/browser-extensions/pdfMake.js#L154. The master branch is for 0.2.x which the readme currently says is unstable (and does not currently have a callback).

Comment: Thanks! As of 2/5/2024 the current v0.2.7 working with DataTable.net v1.13.8 I think has a bug after .download is called it messes up the page url, encoding it - after the download dialog is presented the web page is messed up because the URL is wrong for it (bug). But supplying download function with something setting window.location.href = currentUrl I stored before the call to createPdf/Download that fixes it - the Chrome debugger jumped to that function after the PDF file was downloaded. The current documentation for Download doesn't mention a download function parameter - but it works!